# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: libname: linux-arm.lib not found

Tags: java, rfid

uname -a:

> Linux raspberrypi 4.1.6-v7+ #810 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 18 15:32:12 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

Trying to launch application that controls RFID reader.

```
2016-01-07 21:42:19.593 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - Load config file...
2016-01-07 21:42:19.604 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - modulePort: eapi:///dev/ttyUSB0
2016-01-07 21:42:19.606 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - read_power: 3000
2016-01-07 21:42:19.607 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - measurement_error: 5
2016-01-07 21:42:19.608 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - sleeping_time: 50
2016-01-07 21:42:19.610 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - scanning_time: 150
2016-01-07 21:42:19.611 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - iteration_number: 10
2016-01-07 21:42:19.613 [main]  INFO  rfid.utils.RFIDUtils - Create rfid reader (eapi:///dev/ttyUSB0)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.thingmagic.SerialTransportNative$Factory.createReader(SerialTransportNative.java:247)
        at com.thingmagic.SerialTransportNative$Factory.createReader(SerialTransportNative.java:232)
        at com.thingmagic.Reader.create(Reader.java:270)
        at rfid.utils.RFIDUtils.createReader(RFIDUtils.java:17)
        at rfid.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: libname: linux-arm.lib not found
        at com.thingmagic.SerialTransportNative.load(SerialTransportNative.java:113)
        at com.thingmagic.SerialTransportNative.<clinit>(SerialTransportNative.java:68)
        ... 5 more
```

linux-arm.lib not found - where to find it??

Comment: What application? Where did you get such application?

Comment: custom application, it works on linux systems.

Comment: Is this a compiled application that normally runs on an x86 processor?

Comment: yes, it works on x86

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that this is a compiled application, that works on x86 processors. This sounds like your problem. The Raspberry Pi's processor doesn't use an x86 architecture, or anything close to it. Rather, the RPi 2 uses an arm7 instruction set.

To get it to work on the RPi, you will have to recompile it targeting the RPi's architecture at the very least.  Depending on what it is and what it does, you may need to have sections of the code rewritten to address the hardware differences.